# Mutiple websites on IIS 6 with different IP. One site won't respond

Tags: iis-6, timeout

I have two websites with different domain names hosted on the IIS 6. I have different IP for each one of them with SSL. The sites are running on IIS 6. When i try accessing b.mydomain.com over SSL, i am able to browse the website. But, a.mydomain.com times out connection.

a.mydomain.com is running on the IIS. When i ping the domain, correct IP is detected. what else should i check for? Kind of puzzled because, the second website with a different domain name and ip is accessible.

any pointers would help.

UPDATE:
trying ipconfig/all didn't display the IP address for b.domain.com. trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to reach a.mydomain.com are you trying to just hit a simple file or an actual web application?  In order to simply "test" drop an empty text file on the site.  a.mydomain.com/foo.txt and see if you can at least load a blank page.  If you get nothing then you know you aren't getting to the IIS site.  Did you double check that the IP address for a.mydomain.com is for sure attached to that machine?  Do you get a ping response from that IP address (assuming you allow a ping response).  Post back with findings.

Comment: @Dave: Got a pretty basic question. When i type in the URL, it's supposed the (1) resolved the IP using the DNS and then (2) reach the server at the IP address. After this, (3) the SSL connection is established while accessing the web site. How do i know, in which step i am now?

Comment: @Dave: I tested the URL in digicert SSL checker. The error i am getting for b.domain.com is 
"DNS resolves to x.x.x.x.
No certificates were found.
connect: Connection timed out connect:errno=22".
Seems i have gone past steps 1 and 2 in my previous comment. Any thoughts?

Comment: I forgot about the SSL portion when I first posted.  One thing you can do to verify if the SSL cert is failing... allow port 80 for that domain (http://) just long enough to test and see if you can load the page.  You can (in a way) test the steps in a command window.  Ping your domain (does it resolve correctly to the right IP?) then telnet to that IP on port 443.  If the connection is immediately refused then you aren't reaching it, however if it connects then you are getting there and the problem lies with the Cert.

Comment: Lastly just make sure you have correctly set up your SSL cert in IIS for that site (check it against the one you've got working correctly).